# Why am I losing the navigation back entry when I navigate from one of the pages to another page in my application?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7.1

I have two pages: Page1.xaml and Page2.xaml. Page1.xaml has a listbox in which, when a user selects an item, I do a `NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Page2.xaml", UriKind.Relative));`.

But from Page2.xaml, when I press the hardware Back button, it simply exits the application. Page1.xaml is the startup page of the application.

Comment: I'll believe you'll have to show your code if you want some help.

Comment: @KooKiz Sorry I couldn't figure out what part of the code I should post. Anyway I've found the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an exception when I pressed the Back button on the second page, which was causing the application to close. I never debugged this part and hence never realized.